# My scroll down function is not scrolling down to the same part of the page - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Depending on how far on the page I am the window will scroll a little bit further down from the top of the section I am trying to get to. If I click the button from the top of the page it gets to the correct item, but if I scroll down a little bit further and click the button it goes that much further from the targeted element.

```js
function scrollDown() {
    const $container = $("html, body");
    const $scrollTo = $("#scrollTo");

    $container.animate({ scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top - $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop(), scrollLeft: 0 }, 400);
}
```

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
}

section p {
    height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grey-box">
    <h2 class="h3">Ready to Start?</h2>
    <button class="btn" id="scroll-btn" onclick="scrollDown();">Scroll Down</button>
</div>
<section class="section1">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
<section class="section2">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
<section class="section3" id="scrollTo">
    <h1>SCROLL HERE</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
<section>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `scrollTop`, you added extra calculations by subtracting `.offset().top` of selector `$('html, body')`, adding up from `scrollTop()` of this selector.

You just need to specify how:

```
$container.animate({ scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top, scrollLeft: 0 }, 400);
```

> The `.offset()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (specifically its border box, which excludes margins) relative to the document. Contrast this with `.position()`, which retrieves the current position relative to the offset parent. When positioning a new element on top of an existing one for global manipulation (in particular, for implementing drag-and-drop), `.offset()` is more useful.

> `.offset()` returns an object containing the properties `top` and `left`.

```js
function scrollDown() {
    const $container = $("html, body");
    const $scrollTo = $("#scrollTo");
    $container.animate({ scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top, scrollLeft: 0 }, 400);
}
```

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
}

section p {
    height: 100vh;
}

.btn {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grey-box">
    <h2 class="h3">Ready to Start?</h2>
    <button class="btn" id="scroll-btn" onclick="scrollDown();">Scroll Down</button>
</div>
<section class="section1">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
<section class="section2">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
<section class="section3" id="scrollTo">
    <h1>SCROLL HERE</h1>
</section>
<section>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
<section>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a libero iaculis, ultrices metus in, ultrices odio. Ut elementum diam at maximus ultrices. Vivamus sed tellus ultrices, porttitor leo sit amet, euismod nibh. Nunc
        elit nisi, faucibus quis maximus vel, consequat at est. Suspendisse euismod justo enim, vitae vehicula ante dapibus quis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin efficitur mi
        vitae urna bibendum, vitae consequat felis maximus.
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: yeah, that's right. I see what you did. I was copying some jQuery code from another post. I was trying to understand the offset() method.

Comment: @lachnroll, I've updated my answer to include a description. You can also read more details here - https://api.jquery.com/offset/. I am glad to help :)